# Assertion none when checking column names of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check that the columns of my data frame are in the right order. I used this code

```
def validation_columns(self)
header_input = list(self.data.columns)
assert header_input == ['column1','column2'], log.log_message("ERROR:...")

# log.log_message() is a function to print info in a log.txt file
```

Why do I get the error

```
AssertionError: None
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to the `assert` keyword is not code to be run in the case of a False condition, it is a message to display in the case of a False condition. Because the function `log.log_message(...)` does not return anything, `None` is printed.

If you want to print text to a file if the condition is False, just use a normal `if` statement:

```py
def validation_columns(self):
    header_input = list(self.data.columns)
    if header_input != ['column1','column2']:
        log.log_message("ERROR:...")
```

Comment: Great!! I know your suggestion but as this is a master's dissertation I wanted to show some advanced coding. I disagree because for me the simple code the better. Now, I have some feedback from you (very likely with more experience than me) I feel more confident using the if statement.